# É possível utilizar o operador ternário em várias condições simultaneamente?

Tags: php, operadores

É possível utilizar mais de uma condição por vez ao utilizar o operador ternário?

```
<?php 
    if($ativa == 0): echo "Médico(a) Desativado(a)"; 
    elseif($ativa == 1): echo "Médico(a) Ativo(a)";
    else: echo "Informação Indisponível"; endif;
?>
```

Podem ver que na condição acima há um bloco de `if`/`else`/`elseif`. Haveria uma maneira de transformar o bloco acima usando operador ternário?

Comment: Não encadeia ternários principalmente no php.

Comment: Vou seguir o conselho então. Foi mais uma dúvida se teria e como @rray

Answer (score 11):

Sim é possível mas **NÃO faça encadeamento de ternários** no PHP pois ele faz as avaliações das expressão a partir da esquerda diferente da maioria das linguagens o que na prática retorna resultados estranhos (o do meio) perceba que as outras repostas fizeram o encadeamento mas sempre com parênteses para definir a prioridade.

Exemplo de ternário que retorna o resultado do meio:

```
$ativo = 1;
$r =  $ativo == 0 ? 'Médico(a) Desativado(a)' : 
      $ativo == 1 ? 'Médico(a) Ativo(a)' :
      $ativo == 2 ? 'Outro' : 'else final';
echo $r;
```

A saída : `Outro`

Para consertar esse *side effect*, no PHP 5.3 foi introduzido o operador *elvis* (`?:`), ele retorna a primeira ou a última parte da expressão.  A maneira mais simples que vejo é fazer um array com status:

```
$descricao = array(0 => 'Médico(a) Desativado(a)', 1 => 'Médico(a) Ativo(a)', 2 =>'Outro');

$ativo = 5;
echo $descricao[$ativo] ?: 'Resultado padrão';
```

No PHP 7 pode usar o  *null coalescing* (`??`):

```
echo $descricao[$ativo] ?? 'Resultado padrão';
```

Answer (score 5):

Até é possível, mas é bem gambiarra pra falar a verdade:

```
echo ($ativa == 0) ? "Médico(a) Desativado(a)" : (($ativa == 1) ? "Médico(a) Ativo(a)" : "Informação Indisponível");
```

Na verdade você adiciona um ternário ao *else*.

Answer (score 5):

Não faça isto, fica pouco legível, mas se insistir:

```
echo ($ativa == 0) ? "Médico(a) Desativado(a)" :
     ($ativa == 1) ? "Médico(a) Ativo(a)" :
     "Informação Indisponível";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/MultiConditional.php).

Comment: Realmente fica muito ilegível

Comment: E eu deixei razoável quebrando linha, na mesma linha fica terrível. No te o código original e este nem faz o que parece desejar.

Answer (score 0):

Sim! Fiz isso uma vez e deu certo. Toda vez que colocar uma nova condição temos que colocar a atribuição da variável novamente. Já tentei muito fazer sem atribuir variável, mas não funciona. Fiz até um teste atribuindo qualquer variável mesmo sem utilizá-la e funcionou, mas desfiz essa "gambiarra" e depois refiz atribuindo uma variável de forma correta.

Solução:

```
$ativo = 1;
$r = $ativo == 0 ? "Médico(a) Desativado(a)" :
    $r = $ativo == 1 ? "Médico(a) Ativo(a)" :
    $r = $ativo == 2 ? "Outro" : "else final";
echo $r;
```