# Concatenação em PHP no campo de seleção

Tags: php, html, laravel

Segue minha dúvida referente a concatenação em PHP no código abaixo:

```
<td>{{$projeto->situacao_projeto == 'AA' ? 'Aguardando Autorização' : 'AP' ? 'Aprovado' :'CS' ? 'Cancelado Suspenso' : 'Reprovado'}}</td>
```

O campo de seleção possui 4 tipos e na exibição do resultado só exibe e repete somente o "Cancelado Suspenso" mesmo selecionando tipos diferentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [É possível utilizar o operador ternário em várias condições simultaneamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230908/91)

Comment: O resultado foi o mesmo a repetição de um mesmo tipo.  <td>
 {{($projeto->situacao_projeto == 'AA') ? 'Aguardando Autorização' : 
 ($projeto->situacao_projeto == 'AP') ? 'Aprovado' :
  ($projeto->situacao_projeto == 'CS') ? 'Cancelado Suspenso' : 
   ($projeto->situacao_projeto == 'RP') ? 'Reprovado' : 'Aguardando Autorização'}}</td>

Comment: exatamente como @HugoLeonardo comentou, para cada if deve ter uma nova condição, no caso está fazendo elseif então deve ter uma nova condição.

Comment: Porém @Eduardo esse operador ternário não é recomendável para uma operação condicional complexa, ou seja, utiliza-se para retorno e a lógica implementada for algo pequeno.

Comment: @HugoLeonardo com certeza, sendo mais de um if eu ja não trabalho dessa maneira, faria da forma tradicional sem dúvida alguma.

Comment: @Eduardo segue a resolução do problema. Otimizei a consulta sql da pasta Controller do projeto em questão: DB::raw('(CASE 
                                 WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AA" THEN "Aguardando Autorização"
                                 WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AP" THEN "Aprovado"
                                 WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AA" THEN "Cancelado Suspenso"
                                 ELSE "Reprovado" 
                                 END) AS situacao_projeto'))

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido: Otimizei a consulta no módulo Controller do projeto em questão segue o código de resolução abaixo:

DB::raw('(
CASE

WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AA" THEN "Aguardando Autorização"

WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AP" THEN "Aprovado"

WHEN projetos.situacao_projeto = "AA" THEN "Cancelado Suspenso"

ELSE "Reprovado"

END) AS situacao_projeto'))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]