# Dificuldade de implantar múltiplas opções numa variável condicional para carregar imagem correspondente

Tags: php, variáveis

como todo programador... são 1h30 da manha.... eta nós....

Amigos não to conseguindo fazer uma variavel condicional funcionar... alguém pode me dar uma luz....?

```html
<?php


 $variavel_condicional = $data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["ScoreType"] == 'RESTRICAO' ? '<img src="api/images/com_restricao.png">' : '<img src="api/images/sem_restricao.png">'; // OK FUNCIONA
 
 // ["Class"] VAI RETORNAR UMA LETRA, PODE SER: A, B, C, D OU E e deacordo com a letra que ela retorna preciso que carregue a imagem corresponde a.png ou b.png ou ...
 // poem não estou conseguindo fazer isso... algume pode me ajudar?
 $variavel_condicional_letra = $data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"] == 'A' ? '<img src="api/images/a.png">'  : == 'B' ? '<img src="api/images/b.png">'  :== 'C' ? '<img src="api/images/c.png">'  :== 'D' ? '<img src="api/images/d.png">'  : '<img src="api/images/e.png">';
 
 
 echo "<tr>";
 
 echo '<td>' .$variavel_condicional.'</td>';  // OK FUNCIONA
 
 
 echo '<td>' .$variavel_condicional_letra.'</td>'; 

 echo "</tr>";
 
?>
```

Obrigado amigos...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível utilizar o operador ternário em várias condições simultaneamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230908/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-utilizar-o-operador-tern%c3%a1rio-em-v%c3%a1rias-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-simultaneamente)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que não seja adequado, mas deve resolver:

```
$variavel_condicional_letra = ($data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"] == 'A') ? '<img src="api/images/a.png">'  :($data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"] == 'B') ? '<img src="api/images/b.png">'  : ($data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"] == 'C') ? '<img src="api/images/c.png">'  : ($data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"] == 'D') ? '<img src="api/images/d.png">'  : '<img src="api/images/e.png">';
```

Edit:
Então faça usando um `array` com os valores, creio que seja o mais adequado:

```
$imagem=$data["CreditData"][0]["Score"]["Class"];
$arr=array('A'=>'<img src="api/images/a.png">','B'=>'<img src="api/images/b.png">','C'=>'<img src="api/images/c.png">','D'=>'<img src="api/images/d.png">','E'=>'<img src="api/images/e.png">');

echo $arr[$imagem];
```

Comment: Wees Smith... obrigado pelo retorno.... mas não deu certo... Na verdade quase deu certo... o problema é que ela sempre retorna a opção D, mesmo que o Class seja A ou B ou C sempre me retornar a imagem d.png

Comment: Editei com uma possibilidade.

Comment: Wees Smith, SHOW de bola! Obrigado agora funcionou perfeitamente.... obrigado amigo!